# How do I export a variable from an express route callback that I can access in another file?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to access the **code** in another file.

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/',async (req, res) => {
  const { code } = req.body;
};

module.exports = router
```

I have tried exporting the variable but it doesn't work and shows up as undefined when I import it to the other file. The other file is a controller when I use this code to generate some auth credentials.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want this value to be available at the module level as your question implies: if your route function hasn't run yet (or the `code` value wasn't present in the request), then it will always be `undefined`. You can account for that possibility by using a pattern like this:

```js
// router.cjs

const express = require('express');

let code;
exports.getCode = () => code;

const router = express.Router();
exports.router = router;

router.post('/',async (req, res) => {
  ({ code } = req.body);
});
```

```js
// controller.cjs

const { getCode } = require('./router');

function tryToDoSomethingWithCode () {
  const code = getCode();
  if (typeof code === 'undefined') {
    // code hasn't been set yet
  }
  else {
    // do something with the code value
  }
}
```

However, if your controller participates in the middleware chain, you can just use [`res.locals`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) (request-specific) or [`app.locals`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals) (global to app) to store this state.